# Enlace roto en vista blade

Tags: html, laravel

Tengo el layout padre de la aplicación que contiene la barra lateral y superior (los menús de toda la vida), pero tengo el problema que en algunas plantillas .blade.php los links no siempre funcionan, expongo mi problema:

Tengo esta vista app.blade.php que el principal:

```
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-user nav-item">
                    <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-user-link">
                        <span class="avatar avatar-online">
                            <img src="{{ URL::asset('images/portrait/small/avatar-s-1.png')}}" alt="avatar"><i>
                            </i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="user-name">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                         <a href="{{ url('/worker/show/' . Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)) }}" class="dropdown-item" >
                       <!--<a href="{{ url('/worker/show/.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)') }}" class="dropdown-item">-->
                            <i class="icon-head"></i> Editar Perfil</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-mail6"></i> Correo</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-clipboard2"></i> Tareas</a>
                        <a href="{{url('/home')}}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-calendar5"></i> Calender</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="{{url('/logout')}}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-power3"></i>Salir</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Como podéis observar tengo un menú desplegable en el cual tengo los enlaces a algunas partes de la web. Sin embargo cuando por ejemplo estoy en el home, (que extiende de app.blade.php) ni siquiera se despliega, y me pasa igual solo en 2 o 3 vistas mas. Y extienden perfectamente todas igual: 
Layout hijo:

```
extends('layouts.app')

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/plugins/calendars/fullcalendar.min.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print"/>

@section('content')
   codigo html....
@stop 

@section('javascript')

@stop
```

Puedo poner el codigo de toda la vista pero basicamente es un copia y pega de esto
Podrían explicarme a causa de que pasa esto?

Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Comment: Podrias mostrar la estructura basica de como estas extendiendo tus layouts?

Comment: Vaya, he pegado el mismo codigo 2 veces -.-''

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez en el caso de los links que no funcionan, a qué url te manda? (revisa la barra de direcciones del navegador, o en la parte inferior del navegador al pasar el mouse por el link) pues puede que esté tomando como base la ruta actual y le añada la porción extra que le estás enviando, por lo que funcionaría en la vista padre pero no en las hijas.

Comment: """  <li class="dropdown dropdown-user nav-item"> """" No me funciona cuando pulso en el desplegable este, pulso y no despliega nada, y me pasa solo en algunas vistas hijas, ya que en otras si que funciona el desplegable, y la cosa es que necesito el desplegable para salir.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando la forma como llamas las rutas de **url('ruta')** por **route('as')**.

Por ejemplo, en:

```
<a href="{{url('/home')}}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-calendar5"></i> Calender</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a href="{{url('/logout')}}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-power3"></i>Salir</a>
```

lo cambias por:

```
<a href="{{route('home')}}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-calendar5"></i> Calender</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a href="{{route('logout')}}" class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-power3"></i>Salir</a>
```

Donde el **as**, es el que declaras en la ruta algo de esta forma **'as' => 'home'**

```
Route::get('/home', ['uses'=>'tuControladorController@home','as' => 'home']);
```

Con esto te aseguras que se llame a la ruta exacta, que deseas

Comment: Lo probare a ver si así resuelvo el problema de los links, pero no creo que influyan las rutas, a la hora de que un <li class="dropdown dropdown-user nav-item"> no se despliegue creo yo, o si que influye? Gracias por tu respuesta